# What do the handlers mean in django-achievements documentation?

Tags: django

What do the `accounts.handlers` and `backend.handlers` found in the [documentation](https://django-achievements.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#register-it-to-the-engine) mean?

---

To register it into the engine just use the ‘ACHIEVEMENT_CLASSES‘ attribute in your settings like that :

```
#==========================================================================
# Achievements conf
#==========================================================================
    ACHIEVEMENT_CLASSES = ['accounts.handlers', 'backend.handlers']
```

The file where the classes are defined are not important, but try to avoid conflicts of 
naming by avoiding to use the name *achievements.py*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handler is the file where you write your achievement classes, like it says in the prior step, [Create your first achievement](https://django-achievements.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#create-your-first-achievement).